# kafka-python producer - SSL connection failure - Trustore Only

Tags: python, ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-python, apache-kafka-security

I'm trying to publish messages via python to a kafka topic and am receiving an error.  I can connect and publish via the CLI. Hoping for some guidance. I've googled and read the docs. Thanks!!

Successful CLI command:

```
 kafka-console-producer --broker-list 
 123.45.67.891:1234,123.45.67.892:1234,123.45.67.893:1234 -- 
 producer.config C:\Users\fake_user\Kafka\client-ssl.properties --topic FakeTopic

 Contents of client-ssl.properties:
   security.protocol = SSL
   ssl.truststore.location = C:/Users/fake_user/Kafka/kafka-truststore
   ssl.truststore.password = fakepass
```

Code:

```py
from kafka import KafkaProducer

  producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['123.45.67.891:1234', '123.45.67.892:1234', '123.45.67.893:1234'],
                           security_protocol='SSL',
                           ssl_certfile=r'C:\Users\fake_user\Kafka\kafka-truststore',
                           ssl_password='fakepass')

  producer.send('FakeTopic', value='python_test', key='test')
```

Resultant Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kafka_post_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    ssl_password='fakepass')
  File "C:\Users\fake_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\producer\kafka.py", line 381, in __init__
    **self.config)
  File "C:\Users\fake_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\client_async.py", line 239, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\fake_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\client_async.py", line 874, in check_version
    version = conn.check_version(timeout=remaining, strict=strict, topics=list(self.config['bootstrap_topics_filter']))
  File "C:\Users\fake_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\conn.py", line 1078, in check_version
    if not self.connect_blocking(timeout_at - time.time()):
  File "C:\Users\fake_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\conn.py", line 331, in connect_blocking
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\fake_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\conn.py", line 420, in connect
    if self._try_handshake():
  File "C:\Users\fake_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\conn.py", line 496, in _try_handshake
    self._sock.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\fake_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1051)
```

Comment: Are you able to produce messages with the console producer?

Comment: Yes I am.  Also via KafkaTool.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [link.](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security_ssl)

You have to add the SSL Cert to the JVM keystore for any pretty much any program that is run by Java.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I dug into it. Please know that using the same documentation I'm able to connect with only the truststore file via the console-producer provided with the kafka distribution.  These servers do not require client side certification, so there is no keystore to include.  I'm stuck trying to duplicate the trustsore-only connection with the python library.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that by default, the python-kafka library, sets the ssl_cafile property to None. Setting it to the default os (/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem on linux) allowed me to connect to the kafka brokers.

https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/kafka/producer/kafka.html#KafkaProducer.send

Comment: Thank you for contributing to our community! Please, focus on the question and improve your answer. You can add more formatting and details, which could help in problem solution.